# Why is Calendar class returning incorrect date

Tags: java, date, calendar

Simple bit of code here,   I want to use Calendar in Java to convert date to my desired format. But is is not doing what my data formatter says it should.

```
                public String convertDate( Date date )
                {
            //date = Sun Apr 11 14:10:00 BST 2021   at this point
                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
                    String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);  
            //strDate = 2021-10-11 02:10:00
                    return strDate;
                }
```

Seems the month for the new Calendar is being set to "10".  How do I get it to parse "Apr" part of the date string to the number "04" so my output date should read 2021-04-11 14:10:00

Comment: Use `M` for month: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Your format is wrong. For one, `mm` is obviously either month _or_ minute. It cannot be both!

Comment: Also, use `HH` for 24-hour format of time.

Comment: Never use `Calendar`. That terrible class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use ? DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).